# Rewarding my affiliates

Tags: money-transfer, paypal, gifts, reward-program

I could not find a really fitting site and thoight this is the closest. Otherwise please let me know.

I own a website where I get income from affiliate links. I would like to give back some percentage of my gains to persons who spend their money on my site. What is the best way to go about it?

I have thought about sending the money through PayPal as a thank you gift.

What puzzles me is that it is hard to figure out which person has made the purchase.

I would like to work in a way, the bigger the purchase, the bigger the percentage of the cash back.

Lottery/raffle type of reward does not include the principle above and if I place a sign-up form, in principal anyone with email could sign up for it even those who did not make any purchases.

Edit: 
From the affiliate tracking site avalilable information is: clicked time and country where the click is coming from.

Comment: You can always send it manually. While you can probably connect to PayPal's API to do this automatically there are fees to consider, aside from setting up the automatic processing, but it's most probably possible. Have you considered simpler alternatives to thank your customers? A personal thank you email would go much further than a buck, depending on what you're selling of course. It's correct, however, that this question is most certainly off topic here :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about web-development or product/service functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website had an account functionality, your users would be logged in when they interact with the affiliate link. Then, you would know which accounts interact with the link and reward them appropriately. There’s software you can use to track this information.

I wouldn’t give them a direct cut of the affiliate reward. That’s yours and you earned it by providing great content! I like the idea of raffle. The winner of the raffle could then get a bigger prize. You could also advertise it to encourage people to interact more with the affiliates.

If you wanted to do direct payments, PayPal is probably your best option. Make sure you clearly know who interacted with the affiliates though. People will do anything if they know you’re handing out cash.

I think what your challenge will be is figuring out who exactly made the purchase. The affiliates can’t give you this information exactly, because it would be a violation of privacy.